# Where is the functionality in turnitin to open the original report?

Tags: javascript, moodle

I've got a problem with the turnitin module for Moodle. It works locally to submit and get any plagiarism with a clickable link to the original report. But when I deploy it to my reference server the link is not clickable for a submitted original report.

I want to debug it but I can't create a minimal example because the code is so large. Can you please point me to the functionality in turnitin where the link is for opening the original report in the turnitin module?

### Update

I found the script that opens the original report. If I make a small change then it works but why? Before the change I get that the variable is undefined and after the change it works.

Before:

```
 // Open the document viewer within a frame in a new tab
    function openDV(dvtype, submission_id, coursemoduleid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../plagiarism/turnitin/ajax.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {action: dvtype, submission: submission_id, cmid: coursemoduleid},
            success: function(data) {
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).html(data);
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).children("form").on("submit", function(event) {
                        alert('debug'+submission_id);
                    dvWindow = window.open('/', 'dv_'+submission_id);
                    dvWindow.document.write('<frameset><frame id="dvWindow" name="dvWindow"></frame></frameset>');
                    dvWindow.document.close();
                    $(dvWindow).bind('beforeunload', function() {
                        refreshScores(submission_id, coursemoduleid);
                    });
                });
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).children("form").submit();
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).html("");
            },

        });
    }
```

After:

```
 // Open the document viewer within a frame in a new tab
    function openDV(dvtype, submission_id, coursemoduleid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../plagiarism/turnitin/ajax.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {action: dvtype, submission: submission_id, cmid: coursemoduleid},
            success: function(data) {
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).html(data);
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).children("form").on("submit", function(event) {
                        alert('debug'+submission_id);
                    dvWindow = window.open('<frameset><frame id="dvWindow" name="dvWindow"></frame></frameset>', 'dv_'+submission_id);
                    //dvWindow.document.write('<frameset><frame id="dvWindow" name="dvWindow"></frame></frameset>');
                    dvWindow.document.close();
                    $(dvWindow).bind('beforeunload', function() {
                        refreshScores(submission_id, coursemoduleid);
                    });
                });
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).children("form").submit();
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).html("");
            },

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess... The first parameter for window.open() should be a url.

Maybe there was an error because it can't access the '/' folder on the reference server? Try without the '/'.

```
dvWindow = window.open('', 'dv_'+submission_id);
```